# Detect whether a tkinter pattern is repeating itself

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, graphic

I have a program (more specifically a spirograph) that draws a pattern. After a certain amount of time, it will, inevitably begin to repeat itself. I need a way to detect when that happens.

There are several approaches to this.

1. Detect whether where the line is plotting is on top of a black pixel. Stop after this repeats a few times
2. Somehow pre-calculate the number of iterations it will take to complete a pattern
3. Test for new lines intersecting old ones
4. Store all the points plotted, then stop when the new points generated are the same as older points.

Which method is the best?

Comment: Approach #2 is not that hard.

Comment: How are you drawing the patterns?

Comment: Tkinter canvas connecting calculated points together.

Comment: The entire state of a spirograph can be represented in two numbers, angle and phase. If those repeat, the whole pattern will repeat. (In some edge cases, the pattern _may_ repeat even if those don't, but only a small integer number of times, and you can test for that too with only slightly more complicated math.)

Comment: I think Blender was asking how you _calculate_ the points to connect together.

Comment: Oh. Two arms are displayed onscreen, one rotates around center, other one rotates around the end of the first. Loosely modeled off of [this](http://youtu.be/1w2B4ZjZWyc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach one is out, as research will turn up, tkinter canvases have no direct way to determine the color of a given pixel on them. Approach 2 would be incredibly complicated, and beyond my ability. Approach 3 is impractical as normal patterns regularly self-intersect. But approach 4 worked for me. Here's how I did it:

```
#Detection of whether pattern is repeating itself
        if point2 not in previousPositions:
            previousPositions.append(point2)
            inarow = 0
        else:
            inarow += 1

        if inarow > 5:
            print "Pattern is detected to be repeating itself"
            run = 0
```

This was in a loop where setting `run` to zero stops the loop. This successfully stops graphing the pattern as soon as 5 new points match previously drawn points

### Possible flaws

Some patterns, might, eventually have points that match other points before the graph is over. It is improbable that this will happen more than 5 times. For this to happen, the grapher would have to be moving in a different direction across the same points in a different order. This could be solved by accounting the order of the points occurring. However, it is extremely improbable that this would occur repeatedly, and I was unable to find a pattern that would cause this issue.

Comment: This approach seems good for this problem. But there are other flaws that aren't as unlikely as the one you identified. You can trivially write a chaotic pattern based on an iterative function over the past 8 points, which could then repeat 5 points in a row and then go off in a different direction. (Or you could accidentally write something in non-iterative form that's equivalent to such a function.)  Or, if your points are calculated as floats and rounded or truncated to ints for display, a pattern could just come within 1/2 pixel of repeating itself for more than 5 pixels then diverge.

Comment: The last one is the only one that could happen in my code, through use of the function this is in,

Comment: I think you're right; that's why I said this approach seems good enough for this problem. (Well, as long as you're willing to store a complete set of points drawn, or a bitset of the whole X*Y positions.)

Comment: You can't determine if you're drawing on a black pixel _per se_, but you can certainly determine if you're drawing on top of some other object. You can get the coordinates of objects, and you can tell if objects overlap other objects.

Comment: Oh, but when two lines cross each other in different directions, doesn't that count?